# email in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to make a project about send email in spring boot using `thymeleaf`
but I got an error :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 553 5.1.2 The recipient address  is not a valid RFC-5321 address. n143-v6sm7661221ion.53 - gsmtp

project link is : [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/npxxtumtdmsdly7/sendEmailBoot.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log, you are sending an email to a wrong formatted email address. At which email address did you try to send an email? Maybe you are missing the `@` or the `.` between the hostname and the top level domain.

**UPDATE**: I have found the error in your code:

Your own `MailService` has the following method

```
public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String body) {

        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
        mail.setFrom(from);
        mail.setTo(to);
        mail.setSubject(subject);
        mail.setText(body);

        javaMailSender.send(mail);
    }
```

So you need valid `from` and `to` parameters which have to be valid email address like `yourname@yourdomain.com`.

In your controller you call the method like the following:

`mailService.sendMail("property_mail","contact_mail",subject,message);`

**BUT** `"property_mail"` and `"contanct_mail"` are no valid email adresses ...

The following call would work for example:

`mailService.sendMail("noreply@yourname.com", mail, subject, message);` where `mail` is the parameter you get from your controller method.

Comment: spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=nalkaton@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=mypassword
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

Comment: yes that's your configuration but to which email address did you try to send the email when you get an exception?

Comment: iam trying to send message from **ninos@yahoo.com** to 
**nalkaton@gmail.com** project link is above,thank you

Comment: @Ninos I updated my answer. I found the error in your code